# Move other windows on Mac OS X using Accessibility API

Tags: objective-c, macos, accessibility-api, window-position

I'm trying to use the Accessibility API to change the position of other applications windows.What I wish to do is to get all the windows on the screen from all the applications, then move them all a given offset (lets say 5 or 10 or any value). I am having difficulties doing this since this is day one of programming in Objective-C for me.

Here is what I am doing right now. First, I find the list of windows and their PIDs using `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`. Then, for each window I use `AXUIElementCreateApplication` to get the `AXUIElementRef` of the window. After, that I should use `AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue` with the attribute `kAXPositionAttribute` (which I fail in getting the proper position, always get zeros). Finally, I should add the wanted offset to the position and use `AXUIElementSetAttributeValue` with the attribute `kAXPositionAttribute` and the new position point (which I get runtime errors even if I set absolute values like 0,0).

Can someone help me with a snippet doing what I described above, as I tried many things without any luck. Also, it shouldn't need to be exactly as I decided to implement it above. If there is a better way to go about doing that, then I'll be happy to change it.

**Update:**
As requested in the comment, here is a code snippet of one of the attempts:

```
// Get all the windows
CFArrayRef windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);
NSArray* arr = CFBridgingRelease(windowList);
// Loop through the windows
for (NSMutableDictionary* entry in arr)
{
    // Get window PID
    pid_t pid = [[entry objectForKey:(id)kCGWindowOwnerPID] intValue];
    // Get AXUIElement using PID
    AXUIElementRef elementRef = AXUIElementCreateApplication(pid);
    CFTypeRef position;
    CGPoint point;
    // Get the position attribute of the window (maybe something is wrong?)
    AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(elementRef, kAXPositionAttribute, (CFTypeRef *)&position);
    AXValueGetValue(position, kAXValueCGPointType, &point);
    // Debugging (always zeros?)
    NSLog(@"point=%@", point);
    // Create a point
    NSPoint newPoint;
    newPoint.x = 0;
    newPoint.y = 0;
    position = (CFTypeRef)(AXValueCreate(kAXValueCGPointType, (const void *)&newPoint));
    // Set the position attribute of the window (runtime error over here)
    AXUIElementSetAttributeValue(elementRef, kAXPositionAttribute, (CFTypeRef *)&position);
}
```

Comment: Post the code from one of your attempts, so that people can see what you started with.

Comment: It was explained in steps, and what I had isn't working, so I thought no need for a non-working one. I've updated it with the snippet.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Based on your sample code (slightly modified, as what you posted does not compile and will crash unmodified), I did some experiments.

Here are a few caveats:

- You are retrieving the **Application** by PID, but then acting upon it as if it is a window. That's the core of your problem, but it is only the beginning of the solution.
- You will need to walk the window list for the accessibility application object in order to find relocatable windows that you can move with the Accessibility Framework.
- `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` will return "all on screen" windows when asked the way you're calling it, but it doesn't guarantee that these are either "user windows" or windows with accessibility.   Most menu bar items have a root window which is "on screen" and most of them aren't accessible (which shows up when you try to walk the accessibility tree for the PIDs you retrieve).
- You may find the test for AXRole to be helpful, or you may find other window accessibility attributes more useful in determining whether to move the windows or not.

I've included here modifications to your code (this will run without crashing), which will grab the pertinent window information from the applications you retrieve via PID and then move the windows.   I have a sleep statement so that I could stop execution, since I was just testing for the effect of movement:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#import <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
    // Get all the windows
    CFArrayRef windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);
    NSArray* arr = CFBridgingRelease(windowList);
    // Loop through the windows
    for (NSMutableDictionary* entry in arr)
    {
        // Get window PID
        pid_t pid = [[entry objectForKey:(id)kCGWindowOwnerPID] intValue];
        // Get AXUIElement using PID
        AXUIElementRef appRef = AXUIElementCreateApplication(pid);
        NSLog(@"Ref = %@",appRef);

        // Get the windows
        CFArrayRef windowList;
        AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(appRef, kAXWindowsAttribute, (CFTypeRef *)&windowList);
        NSLog(@"WindowList = %@", windowList);
        if ((!windowList) || CFArrayGetCount(windowList)<1)
            continue;


        // get just the first window for now
        AXUIElementRef windowRef = (AXUIElementRef) CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( windowList, 0);
        CFTypeRef role;
        AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(windowRef, kAXRoleAttribute, (CFTypeRef *)&role);         
        CFTypeRef position;
        CGPoint point;

        // Get the position attribute of the window (maybe something is wrong?)
        AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(windowRef, kAXPositionAttribute, (CFTypeRef *)&position);
        AXValueGetValue(position, kAXValueCGPointType, &point);
        // Debugging (always zeros?)
        NSLog(@"point=%f,%f", point.x,point.y);
        // Create a point
        CGPoint newPoint;
        newPoint.x = 0;
        newPoint.y = 0;
        NSLog(@"Create");
        position = (CFTypeRef)(AXValueCreate(kAXValueCGPointType, (const void *)&newPoint));
        // Set the position attribute of the window (runtime error over here)
        NSLog(@"SetAttribute");
        AXUIElementSetAttributeValue(windowRef, kAXPositionAttribute, position);
        sleep(5);
    }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, Thanks! Up-voted, and selected. However, could you please elaborate on the use of AXRole, how is it going to be useful in this case?

Comment: @tria AXRole (depending on its use by the apps whose windows are available) may help you to decide which windows to move, such as `kAXSystemWideRole`, `kAXSheetRole`.  You can look around your own system with `Accessibility Inspector` (installed as part of Xcode these days).

Comment: @gaige it seems that `AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(appRef, kAXWindowsAttribute, (CFTypeRef *)&windowList);` in `macOS Sierra` will not return any window.

Comment: @loretoparisi I see that too re-running my test jig.  I'm guessing it has to do with the permission model, as I haven't tried this in a full application where I can grant Accessibility permissions.

Comment: @gaige Any Idea how to do this in Swift? I cannot get it working with all that pointer things

Comment: @mica I really haven't played much with Swift and AX yet. You might try splitting the above into methods and then using Xcode's ability to use Swift and Objective-C side-by-side to access the methods.

Comment: @gaige Tnx, tries something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47480873/set-the-size-and-position-of-all-windows-on-the-screen-in-swift