# OSX position of specific window

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm new to OS X programming, but what I'm looking to do is find the dimensions and positions of a specific window ( of a specific process) , then ultimately create a frame capture over that to simulate a screen recording of a specific application programmatically.

How does one find a specific window (Swift) , more specifically what API would I need. It appears the apple docs are a complete mess and I see several apis that touch on this functionality.

Any guidance or sample would be helpful here.

Comment: For your first question, you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069066/move-other-windows-on-mac-os-x-using-accessibility-api

Comment: I suggest that you go over the code of [Son of Grab](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SonOfGrab/Introduction/Intro.html), an Apple demo that does exactly what you described.